# Can i call a php function using a string?

Tags: php

I want to call a php function using a string. I know i can do it with a single function but can i do something like the code below?

```
model->{'function'}; // this works
model->{'function->childMethod'}; // what i want
```

Comment: `model->{'function'}->{'childMethod'}`?

Comment: Thank you. I already thought about that, is there anyway i can do this using only 1 string? (i am trying to avoid to check for each string if i have a separator or something because i am doing it in a huge loop)

Comment: No, as the string inside would be evaluated to that string exactly. You're probably getting into something which leads to bad practices - I don't know exactly what you're doing, but this could easily backfire. Just a thought.

Comment: I will try to do is in another way. Thank you for your answer